# How to deliver different Responsive Images?

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, yii, responsive-design

On this website:

- .php
- .jquery
- .yii based

We need to have two or more different infographic pictures, depending on the viewport width.

- *The client is picky about w3c validation*
- *picturefill solution doesn't validate*
- *different images and not only different image version, should be served*
- *for a lot of reasons* background images are not a solution*
- *IE8 and up support*

I can use either a server or client side version, no problem.

**Reasons:**

1. Background image technique does work, but those infographics are NOT background.
2. They should arrive server side.
3. Obviously, they need to adapt. (and background size... well...)
4. Even worst, we do have responsive tooltips image maps associated with those infographics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If media queries is not what you want then use [response.js](http://responsejs.com/#examples), if done properly you can load `<img>`s too. Here is a example:

```
<-- Load lo-fi.png  when viewport is 0–480px wide or no-js. 
    Load medium.png when viewport is 481–1024px wide. 
    Load hi-fi.png  when viewport is 1025px+ wide. --> 

<img src="lo-fi.png" data-src481="medium.png" data-src1025="hi-fi.png" alt="example" />
```

Comment: It's not that I don't want, is that I can't have. ;)

Comment: I tried that, the script is loaded but the images don't seem to switch. Should I call something after inserting or something ? Would this work after resize AND document.ready ?

Comment: found it. forgot to add Response.create to trigger the all thing. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `background-image` property and then with media queries change that for every viewport width.

BTW As far as W3C validation goes, you're probably doing your site in HTML5 which doesn't have an official validator yet ;)

Comment: If internet explorer compatibility is an issue, use the filter property to check width and set the background image. (you can use the conditional comments hack to make it validate, it will only read it on internet explorer)

Comment: Another possibility if IE8 and older compatibility is an issue is to use http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: I've updated my question. I will not argue with the client if HTML5 Validator is official or not. But if it's on W3C website, I can't see how more "official" can we get. ;)

Comment: Well if you try their HTML5 validator you get a warning "Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker." and then later on it tells you you are not using their service but [validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/) So while it is on their website, it is there only for convenience - it is not their product ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use media queries.
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://cssmediaqueries.com/

Just have a different style applied to the container and swap out images based on the viewport size. Of course, this would require setting the image as a background, not using an img tag.

Comment: If media queries are out, Javascript is really the only viable alternative. See Starx answer.